# Express and React, send CSURF token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, http, csrf

I have a NodeJs server running some app using EJS,
now I want to add a React app.

But I don't quite manage to send the csrf token back to the server from React.

Here's my server setup:

```
const csrfMiddleware = csurf({
  cookie: true,
});
app.use(csrfMiddleware);
```

Here I'm trying to send it from the frontend:

```
 let _csrf = cookie.load("_csrf");
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "CSRF-Token": _csrf,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      };
```

But this doesn't work, I get `ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token`.
How am I supposed to get the csrf without breaking the current server functionality?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I tried figuring it out myself, don't know if it's the best option (probably not), but this is what worked for me.

server:

```
app.get("/getcsrf", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ _csrf: req.csrfToken() });
});
```

React:

```
 const { data: csrfData } = await axios.get("/api/campaign/getcsrf");
```

What I did was, add a route on the server, to get the generated csrf token.

and fetch it on the client-side when needed.

2 problems:

1. need to call this before every post-request
2. don't know how secure it is.

but at least it works

Comment: this is so pointless, and not how csrf should be used.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What's the way to do it?